# JSF and usage of gdata maps or js maps api

Tags: jsf, google-maps, gdata-api

I am building jsf component for map servers and I was wondering if it is possible to use gdata  maps api to update or retrieve new map which isn' t user map or i have to create Javascript binding for JSF.

Regards
Jan

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces has a google maps component including ajax support, examples can be found at http://www.primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase/ui/gmapHome.jsf

Maybe you can use this as a starting point instead of creating one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of Google Maps.  They require a license which costs 17,500 a year.